# Pretty dict initialization ( Perl style )

Tags: python, dictionary

In Perl initialization a hash of hashes looks like this:

```
  my %data_ops = (
    data1 => { 
      conv_to_num   => \&data1_to_num, 
      conv_to_str   => \&data1_to_str, 
      gen_rand_val  => \&data1_gen_rand,
    },

    data2 => { 
      conv_to_num   => \&data2_to_num, 
      conv_to_str   => \&data2_to_str, 
      gen_rand_val  => \&data2_gen_rand,
    },
  );
```

Is there a way to do the same in Python?

Comment: See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong with the default dict literal syntax:

```
data_ops = {
    'data1': { 
        'conv_to_num':  data1_to_num, 
        'conv_to_str':  data1_to_str, 
        'gen_rand_val': data1_gen_rand,
    },

    'data2': { 
        'conv_to_num':  data2_to_num, 
        'conv_to_str':  data2_to_str, 
        'gen_rand_val': data2_gen_rand,
    },
}
```

or you could use the `dict()` constructor, provided your keys are also valid python identifiers:

```
data_ops = dict(
    data1=dict( 
        conv_to_num=data1_to_num, 
        conv_to_str=data1_to_str, 
        gen_rand_val=data1_gen_rand,
    ),

    data2=dict( 
        conv_to_num=data2_to_num, 
        conv_to_str=data2_to_str, 
        gen_rand_val=data2_gen_rand,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Python might look something like this (I just used constants to show the structure clearly):

```
data_ops = {
  'data1': {
    'conv_to_num': 1,
    'conv_to_str': '1',
    'gen_rand_val': 6,
  },

  'data2': {
    'conv_to_num': 2,
    'conv_to_str': '2',
    'gen_rand_val': 3,
  },
}
```

Examples showing access:

```
>>> data_ops['data1']['conv_to_num']
1
>>> data_ops['data2']['gen_rand_val']
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to use Perl syntax with Python. But of course, you can initialize dicts in Python.

```
data_ops = {
    data1: { 
        "conv_to_num": data1_to_num, 
        "conv_to_str": data1_to_str, 
        "gen_rand_val": data1_gen_rand,
    },

    data2: { 
        "conv_to_num": data2_to_num, 
        "conv_to_str2: data2_to_str, 
        "gen_rand_val": data2_gen_rand,
    },
}
```

The important point is to open the braces on the line with the `=` assignment, this will tell the compiler to continue the statement/expression until the matching brace is found.

Comment: @kindall Not necessarily so. From the original P*erl code I assumed that those were identifiers defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Nope, those are keys. The Perl `=>` operator adds quotes around the identifier to its left.

Comment: @kindall Thanks, didn't realize that. This is one more reason for me to avoid P*rl...